# How to select html <option> where text=Washington

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to select html  where text=Washington
I am doing it like

```
var opt = $("#address_states_state option[text='Washington']");
var html = $("<div>").append(opt.clone()).html();
html = html.replace(/\>/, ' selected="selected">');
opt.replaceWith(html);
```

Comment: use jquery functionality like attr() instead of manipulating the html code http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can just do this using the [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```
$("#address_states_state option:contains('Washington')").prop('selected', true);
```

instead of doing a **clone** and then replacing it with a **selected** option.

Demo : [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fAR9V/)

**UPDATE**

If you want to select the option having a specific text (*in your case, 'Washington'*), you can do this:

```
$('#address_states_state option').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text().toLowerCase() === 'washington';
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Demo : [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fAR9V/2/)

Comment: What if the option was "Washington, England"? This is wrong. See @billyonecan's answer for a more robust, complete solution.

Comment: @LeonardChallis: But we can only select one option at a time, right? I think that is what OP's requirement is!

Comment: @LeonardChallis: Also this works when the option is "_Washington, England_" [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fAR9V/1/)

Comment: You're missing the point. He asked when `text=Washington` - not when it **contains** Washington. What if there were more than one option containing Washington?

Comment: @LeonardChallis: I have updated the code. I hope it meets the OP's requirement correctly now... Is it ok now?

Answer (score 2):

There's no direct selector for getting elements where its `text` equals `X`. There are a couple of things you can do though:

You could use `filter()`:

```
$('#address_states_state option').filter(function(i, el) {
   return $(el).text() === 'Washington'
});
```

Or, write your own pseudo selector:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].textEquals = $.expr.createPseudo(function( text ) {
    return function(elem) {
        return $(elem).text() === text;
    }
});
```

Then you'd just do:

```
$('#address_states_state option:textEquals("Washington")')
```

#### [Here's an example of the latter](http://jsfiddle.net/YEUtV/16/)

Comment: Being the only correct answer, this shouldn't have a downvote.